# aws cloudformation estimate-template-cost returning non-working URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to get more familiar with the costs around using AWS. I am trying to use `aws cloudformation estimate-template-cost` with one of the AWS quickstart templates.

Here is my command, which returns a URL:

```
$: aws --region="us-west-2" cloudformation estimate-template-cost --template-url="https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/hashicorp/vault/latest/templates/quickstart-hashicorp-vault-master.template" --parameters='[{"ParameterKey":"KeyPairName","ParameterValue":"","UsePreviousValue":false},{"ParameterKey":"AccessCIDR","ParameterValue":"0.0.0.0/0","UsePreviousValue":false},{"ParameterKey":"EmailAddress","ParameterValue": "","UsePreviousValue": false},{"ParameterKey":"AvailabilityZones", "ParameterValue":"us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2c","UsePreviousValue":false}]'
{
    "Url": "http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html?key=cloudformation/500b0d9e-22fd-400a-bfa3-7ad34dfeb592"
}
```

The URL returned just brings me to the cost calculator website without any information filled out, just blank forms.

I noticed also that when I tried to launch this template manually in the AWS Console, there is no link available:

[image]

The parameters I filled out in the Console match the ones in the command.  Is there something wrong with the parameters/options as I've filled them out? Or, is there something concerning the AWS account I should look for that won't let me perform this action?

Comment: in case anyone else is wondering which resource types are supported by `estimate-template-cost`: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it appears I simply chose the wrong template to test against, as this template only spins up VPC resources, which do not cost anything.